# definitionNameError when Accessing Local Variable Outside of Class

Tags: ruby

The exact error I am getting is `definitionNameError: undefined local variable or method 'a' for A:Class    from (irb):2:in 'send'  from (irb):2    from :0`

Say, I've got a class definition,

`class A; a = 1; end`

How could get the value of 'a' outside of A?

I've tried:

`eval 'p a', A.send(:binding)`

failed, said:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for A:Class
from (irb):2:in `send'
from (irb):2
from :0
```

Comment: Can I ask *why* you need to dig directly into a class to get a single local variable? What's the larger picture?

Comment: to Telemachus,

Actually, it's not me want to dig into the class, it's a test from 

http://ruby-metaprogramming.heroku.com/html/Exercise_1.html

Answer (score 1):

A block (closure) automatically captures and carries with it the bindings from the code location where it was created (created => block is also an object):

Hence local variable of a class can be accessed using Lambda, which preserves the current state of local variable when it is created. So here we go,

```
class A
  a = 100  
  # creating lambda at class level as 'a' is a local variable of class A
  @l = lambda { a } 
  class << self
    attr_reader :l
  end
end
puts A.l.call # => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think so** (without resorting to source-inspection). A binding is ultimately tied to some lexical scope: how to access it from another unless it's been stored? The example below cheats, of course.

```
b = class A
  x = 20
  binding
end

eval "p x", b
```

This may also be implementation-specific (on 1.8.7 but not 1.9, for instance). I have tried all the combinations of bindings and/or local_variables that I can think of and still no love. Of course, I could just be *doing it wrong*. It would be nice to see a solution.

Comment: good one, the point here is to access the local variable without returning the binding

Answer (score 0):

With that precise definition, there is a way:

```
secret_val = class A; a = 1; end
puts a
```

Otherwise, once the class definition context goes away, that local variable disappears.

Wait. In the original quiz question you linked to in the comments, those are instance variables, not locals. That's cake. Just use `instance_variable_get("@a")` on the class and an instance, respectively.

Comment: to Chuck,

serect_val = class A; a = 1; end
puts secret_val

will print 1 to the screen, that's correct, but how could you get the value of 'a' if it's not the last expression in the class definition?

Comment: @Chuck there is 'a' in addition to @a and @@a :(